# Cannot access attribute in Thymeleaf

Tags: spring, thymeleaf

[i got my student controller here and listStudent atribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6lQLa.png)

[but in my index.html it cannot get atribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/72P1e.png)

Thanks for reading and helping me

Comment: Your model attribute's name is `students`. But in Thymeleaf you are using a different value: `listStudent` in `${listStudent}`. Try changing that to `${students}`.

Comment: Please also take a look at why you should not upload [images of code, data, errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/12567365) when asking a question. You can read [ask] for more background.

Comment: thank you for helping and reminding me how to ask a question on here

Answer (score 0):

as andrewJames mentioned already, you will need to access your List the same way you defined it.

Say you use the following Controller as you defined:

```
@GetMapping("/")
public String viewHomePage(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("students", studentService.getAllStudents());
    return "index";
}
```

Then you will need to use "students" in your Thymleaf Template to access the List.

```html
<tr th:each="student : ${students}">
    <td th:text="${student.getScode()}">ID</td>
    <td th:text="${student.getSname()}"></td>
    <td th:text="${student.getDid()}"></td>
    <td th:text="${student.getGid()}"></td>
    <td th:text="${student.getSsid()()}"></td>
</tr>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: yes thank you for your help. let me try it